# separate task manager for each user

Tags: c#

Is there a possibility in the windows system to separate the task tree so that one user's processes would be invisible to another? The only thing I found was rootkit source codes, but this method interferes with the anti-virus and the entire security system. Is there any other option?

Comment: Users cannot *affect* other users programs unless they have admin rights (at which point, all the rules are out the window)

Comment: You can make a service. It will be in service list, but people dont look at service list.

Comment: The computer game security system detects the launch of a second game client even on another user, I suspect that it has an insight into all running processes in the system, just like when pressing the "show processes of all users" button. Here is the problem - how to avoid: /

Comment: I guess the problem is not easy to solve, because the security is run as a service

Comment: What computer game security system? How is it related to C#? What code have you got?

Comment: But why do you want a separate task manager? The task manager is just an UI over Windows.

Comment: Task manager has nothing to do with the ability to create global objects, which is almost certainly how any "computer game security system" is finding other running instances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is no. But if you have admin rights you can get a little batch script to use rootkit to hide processes depending on the current user. Or even create a program in your framework of wish to do that. Anyway good hidden processes run at kernal level to get there use the windows driver kit or rootKit.